# MKMapSnapshotter in MKTileOverlay appears displaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I'm overriding the `loadTileAtPath:result:` method of `MKTileOverlay` with the following code. It simply converts the `MKTileOverlayPath` into an MKMapRect, and then uses `MKMapSnapshotter` to take a snapshot of the map area that's being looked at. From there, I'd do further work using the image of the map. But for now, I'm just returning the snapshots as the resulting data, so I can see how well they represent the map.

```
- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path
                result:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error))result
{
    double divisions = pow(2, (float)path.z);

    MKMapSize tileSize = MKMapSizeMake(MKMapSizeWorld.width / divisions, MKMapSizeWorld.height / divisions);

    MKMapPoint tilePoint = MKMapPointMake(path.x * tileSize.width, path.y * tileSize.height);

    MKMapRect tileRect = MKMapRectMake(tilePoint.x, tilePoint.y, tileSize.width, tileSize.height);
    MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
    options.mapRect = tileRect;
    options.size = CGSizeMake(tileSize.width, tileSize.height);
    options.showsBuildings = NO;
    options.showsPointsOfInterest = NO;
    options.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        result(UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapshot.image), nil);
    }];
}
```

Given that the math here is all correct, in theory it should display a perfect map. Instead, it displays this:

[image]

And this is what it should look like (what the map below looks like):

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying something similar but get an error "Bad MKMapSnapshotOptions." I think it has something to do with the tile size.

Answer (score 0):

The "Bad MKMapSnapshotOptions" message is likely due to incorrect `size` in the options. The size cannot be too big (it seems 5000px is ok, but 1000px is too big). The size also cannot have sub-pixel sizes, so 123.4px is invalid. Make sure you use `round()` when you produce the size.